# Android change layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-activity

I have situation where I want to change layout of activity after 3 seconds. Ho can I do that?
For example application starts with splashscreen that will run for 3 seconds then automatically switch layout to application's first screen layout. This should happen in the same activity, any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did this using only one xml layout. I just put an extra RelativeLayout in it that represents my intro screen then I use a fadeOut Animation on it and then call .setVisibility(View.GONE).

This is part of my main.xml layout file

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/introLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="#FFFFFF"
    >

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo">
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Then inside my activity I have this:

```
introLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.introLayout);
Animation fadeOutAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MyActivity.this, R.anim.fadeout);
introLayout.startAnimation(fadeOutAnim);
introLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

You could make this run after 3 seconds by putting the startAnimation(), and the setVisibility inside of a runnable and using postDelayed() as markus mentioned. Do consider doing some work while this intro layout is on the screen though, so its not just a 3 second delay for the user. Perhaps check to see if the running version of the application is the current version or not.

**EDIT:** 
You'll need to  add the fadout.xml file to `/res/anim/` (create the anim directory if it doesn't exist). Here is an example.

**fadeout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="700" 
       android:fillAfter="true"/>
```

Comment: where does the `.anim.` in `R.anim.` goes? I get a `anim cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: @w0rldart you need to add fadeout.xml to `/res/anim/` folder, see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the ViewSwitcher,using this one can switch between any number of layouts within the application without having to do any setContentView.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you could use a postDelayed()-call to execute a runnable that will load a new xml file by calling setContentView(R.xml.anotherxml).

Answer (score 1):

This leaves me to add to adnorid's post, that ViewSwitcher itself is only able to switch between 2 layouts/views. This is simply because it's hardcoded to only 2 layouts/views without deeper meaning, as far as i know. So i built my own MultipleViewSwitcher aka MVS, base on the original ViewSwitcher.java from android source. The only changes that had to be made are:

1. Provide the MVS with own

   - boolean mFirstTime and
   - int mWhichChild
2. Correct hardcoded into dynamic handling of an arbitrary number of views in functions

   - addView(...)
   - getNextView()
   - reset()

This can all be done in MultipleViewSwitcher.java alone and works like a charm.

I came accross a bunch of stuff like that where the android sources could be made much more powerful with, many times, near-no-brainer-edits. I'd like to know why that is, but that's not for this thread here.

cheers!