# Android switching views

Tags: android, animation, layout, view, switch-statement

Ok, so I have worked the fading out content from within an `id` (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4570977/971392).

I have the following function:

```
public void switchView(View view) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
        View to_load = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_register, null, false); 

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_login);
        Animation fadeOutAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(LoginActivity.this, R.anim.fadeout);
        rl.startAnimation(fadeOutAnim);
        //rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //rl.removeView(view);
        rl.addView(to_load);
}
```

It does the desired action, **IF I comment the** `rl.startAnimation(fadeOutAnim)` which is there only for the purpose of giving an animation on change view.

With the animation executing, the function changes the view through the `rl.addView()` but then applies the `fadeOut` and everything disappears.

So, how may I use the fadeout, without it removing my content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to delay the `rl.addView(to_load);` call until after the fade out animation is complete. The way to do that is with an Animation Listener.

Try like this:

```
AnimationListener animListen = new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        rl.addView(to_load);
    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }
});

Animation fadeOutAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(LoginActivity.this, R.anim.fadeout);
fadeOutAnim.setAnimationListener(animListen);
rl.startAnimation(fadeOutAnim);
```

Comment: will try tomorrow and let you know

Comment: did you call `addView(to_load);` ?

Comment: `rl.addView` is the one you need I think based on the code in your question

Comment: yes yes, that's what I have been working with... if I comment the fadeout effect and leave the `rl.addView` I get a partial replace "

Comment: is the view `to_load` set to visible ?