# Change from Layout 1 to Layout 2 on Android with button

Tags: android, layout, button

I have two layouts that I want to change between each other when clicking a button.
They are full screen views like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF0000"
tools:context=".FullscreenActivity" >
```

and I want them to change between them when clicking

```
 <Button
 android:id="@+id/green_button"
 style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:text="@string/green" />
```

Am I supposed to change something in src/com.example.layout/fullscreenactivity.java onClick() or where can I change so this happens?

Big thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
layout1 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
layout2 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout2);
layout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.green_button);

mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.green_button);
rb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.OtherLayout);
// now in order to use other layout button, image or any child function you have to declare it under the                 setContentView(R.layout.OtherLayout);

    }
});
```

please do accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be having both FrameLayouts applied, and in `onClickListener` only change visibility of one to `visible` and the other to `gone`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your activity where you utilize the framelayout and the button, you will have to add a listener for the button and the appropriate actions to happen when the button is clicked (in your case - change the layout)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to declare both layouts in one `xml` file and then use `setVisibility(View.GONE)` to remove particular layout. You can see this in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570236/android-change-layout-dynamically) stackoverflow question.