# Change Layouts Dynamically in 1 Activity

Tags: java, android, layout

I have the same request of this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570236/android-change-layout-dynamically) and I followed the [FoamyGuy's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4570977/1629278) but I don't get the introLayout with the ImageView displaying.

I just want to show my introLayout first and then change it to my WebView.

here is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/introLayout"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:visibility="visible"
    >

        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:contentDescription="splash screen"
                   android:id="@+id/splash"
                   android:src="@drawable/splash"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <WebView
            android:id="@+id/browser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            RelativeLayout introLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.introLayout);
            introLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);
            webview.setVisibility(1);
    }
```

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Your `introLayout` is set `View.GONE`, change to

```
introLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

You need to make some logic in your code, when you will hide this "@+id/introLayout" and then show your `WebView`.

Ok, here is how would i do that if you dont need that layout after few seconds:

**ActivityMain**

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(3000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent startSpalsh = new Intent("com.yourpackagename.secondactivity");
                startActivity(startSpalsh);

            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    finish();
   }


}
```

**splash.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/introLayout"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:background="@color/white"
   android:visibility="visible">

   <ImageView 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:contentDescription="splash screen"
      android:id="@+id/splash"
      android:src="@drawable/splash"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**SecondActivity**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

WebView webView;
TextView txtChk;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);
}
```

**second.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">


 <WebView
        android:id="@+id/browser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible" />  

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want that introLayout displays first and then hide, that is why is View.GONE at that point

Comment: No, you set your "@+id/introLayout" to be hidden by default.

Comment: @Rafael Reyes I wrote some code, maybe you' ll find something useful.

Comment: thanks for your answer! but it could be donde in one single activity?

Comment: Yes, it could but i decided to show you this code, you can use it for splash screen later, for your logo or something similar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103034/discussion-between-rafael-reyes-and-stanojkovic).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it would make any difference but you could try :

webview.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);

Instead of :

webview.setVisibility (1);

PS: With View.GONE you make the View not visible and with View.VISIBLE you make the View visible :).
Just because you did the opposite thing in your MainActivity then you discribed.

Answer (score 0):

First, change de ubication of intro. Set it below of WebView in your layout. WebView and intro don't need to set tag visibility. So... In your onCreate() apply this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { introLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); } }, 2000);
```

2000 = 2 seconds. Change this like you want.

This code will be later that your initialize WebView and IntroLayout.

Change the LinearLayout by RelativeLayout in your layout how principal container.